# Strange Chrome behavior: calculates all margin percentages right except for margin-top!

Tags: css, google-chrome, margin

When I declare this style for a div:

```
#fbInner{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 11.2% 9.7% 0% 26.4%;
    width: 63.5%;
    height: 54.6%;
    overflow: visible;
    /*max-height: 190px;
    max-width: 490px;*/
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    /*border: solid 2px gray;*/
}
```

Chrome sets every margin right except of the margin top, which is set much smaller than in other browsers ... strange, all other margins are displayed like it should ...

What is the reason for that?
Is there a workaround that still uses percentages?

Comment: It seems to be working correctly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/xixionia/dPZWF/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as this is an x-browser css question, resetting the css styles would be a valuable first step - maybe even the solution. You haven't disclosed any HTML code, so I can't know what other tags or styles are affecting `#fbInner`

In any case, here is the "meyerweb reset" stylesheet: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Link it topmost in your HTML file. It will probably break your site, but that's a good thing. At least it should be equally broken in all browsers now. When you've fixed the look of your page, it should work properly in most/all browsers.

Comment: thx ... the problem was a google chrome bug:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=80774

Comment: but i used the css reset for some other stuff :-)